# Using javascript push to add user set product quantity to the cart

Tags: javascript

I currently have a working shopping cart using a php form with a button with onclick to add the product to the cart. Ive just added a text input for quantity. Tried a few things and cant get my head around how to do make this work, Im pretty good with php but javascript I am pretty new to.

So my onclick event is:

```
onclick="return addToBasket(<?php echo $item['item_id']; ?>);"
```

The function:

```
function addToBasket(itemId){
cartItems.push(items[itemId]);
updateCart();
return false;}
```

So i get how i could push multiple **different** elements into the cart array but its the quantities of one element defined by the user thats stumped me. I think I need to use document.getElementById('quantity').value in the onclick and then use that in the function but not sure how and all my searches came up with nothing. Am I on the right lines or miles adrift?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: What error or result are you getting currently?

Comment: Its not so much an error and more that I dont know how to use the quantity value in the function. push(items[itemId], quantity) will try and add a second product. How can i times the items[itemId] by the value quantity?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Is this even possible using push? Maybe I need to try something else, this is the last thing to implement the cart works great other than this bit :(

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on what your question is specifically. I think you might need a different data structure than an Array to hold two different values (item id and quantity of that item). Have you considered using an object instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'm going to answer my own question. In hindsight making an object may have been easier but as the store is all set up and works nice with the array i decided to stick with it.

Basically I just used

```
document.getElementById('qty').value
```

and then in the function i did a for loop to add the product to the array as many times as the quantity is

```
for (var i=0; i < qty; i++) {
    cartItems.push(items[itemId]);
}
```

actually really obvious now i look at it. But im quite new to javascript so meh. Cheers for the help Patrick Beeson anyway!